# GCP - Cannot auth with google platform in ruby with service account attached to instance

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

We have Instance 1 from Project A trying to reach Cloud Function v1 API from Project B, using a service account (lives on Project A) assigned to the instance, via ruby code.

Instance 1 has the service account assigned to it within "Api and Identity Management".

I am able to successfully curl the API from Instance 1. Basically using this one liner...

```
curl -m 70 -G https://{projectofAPI}.cloudfunctions.net/{functionname}?hostName=somehostname -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

The server is Debian 11 and the service account has the correct permissions which are Cloud Functions Invoker and Cloud Run Invoker (which is assigned in IAM from the project where the API lives.

We are using ruby 2.5.9. Google SDK is fully updated, and using googleauth gem for authing to GCE environment in ruby

Here is the code...

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'
require 'googleauth'

# The URL of the function
url = 'https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME'

# Fetch the access token
scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
authorizer = Google::Auth::GCECredentials.new
authorizer.fetch_access_token!

# Set the headers
headers = {
  Authorization: "Bearer #{authorizer.access_token}",
  content_type: :json, 
  accept: :json,
  'hostName': 'test.corp.internal'
}

# Call the function
response = RestClient.get(url, headers)

# Print the response
puts response
```

The response from the API is 401 unauthorized.

When printing out the email service credential from `puts authorizer.service_account_email`
This leads me to believe that it is actually not obtaining the correct credential.

Things I've tried to identify whether the instance is in fact able to see the service account assigned to it...
`curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/email" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`
This actually returns the correct service account.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Expecting Ruby to be able to auth into Google with the service account that is assigned to the instance, and thereby producing a result of hitting the cloud function API.

Basically to get authentication to work with the correct service account when running ruby scripts.

Comment: It is not clear from your question, if the service account in project A has been given access to the call cloud function in project B. This needs to be done through IAM in project B through cloud console or through gcloud cli..

Comment: That is correct, I have delegated the appropriate permissions within Project B's IAM console.

Comment: Do you have any service account set to env var `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`? Follow this guide - https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc